# How does java.c determine which to call since there are three function implementations for different systems in Jdk8?

Tags: java, c, java-8, jvm, jvm-hotspot

What puzzles me is how it determines which to call when entering the function *JVMInit*(as well as *LoadJavaVM*) in *jdk/src/share/bin/java.c* since there are three function implementations in different files, namely *jdk/src/windows/bin/java_md.c*,
*jdk/src/solaris/ bin/java_md_solinux.c*,
*jdk/src/macosx/bin/java_md_macosx.c*

Part code in java.c:

```
int
JLI_Launch(int argc, char ** argv,              /* main argc, argc */
        int jargc, const char** jargv,          /* java args */
        int appclassc, const char** appclassv,  /* app classpath */
        const char* fullversion,                /* full version defined */
        const char* dotversion,                 /* dot version defined */
        const char* pname,                      /* program name */
        const char* lname,                      /* launcher name */
        jboolean javaargs,                      /* JAVA_ARGS */
        jboolean cpwildcard,                    /* classpath wildcard*/
        jboolean javaw,                         /* windows-only javaw */
        jint ergo                               /* ergonomics class policy */
)
{
    int mode = LM_UNKNOWN;
    char *what = NULL;
    char *cpath = 0;
    char *main_class = NULL;
    int ret;
    InvocationFunctions ifn;
    jlong start = 0, end = 0;
    char jvmpath[MAXPATHLEN];
    char jrepath[MAXPATHLEN];
    char jvmcfg[MAXPATHLEN];

    ...

    if (!LoadJavaVM(jvmpath, &ifn)) {
        return(6);
    }

    ...

    return JVMInit(&ifn, threadStackSize, argc, argv, mode, what, ret);
}
```

I was only able to find the corresponding function implementations in the three files, and due to my unfamiliarity with C/C++, I was unable to find how it determines which one to enter in the jdk8 source code.

I hope someone can help point out how it works.

P.S. The jdk8 source code I've been reading comes from https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/releases/tag/jdk8u392-ga.zip

Comment: Likely via platform-dependent makefiles, or whatever is used to compile the source code. TL;DR, when you compile the source code, the build system detects which OS you're running (or accepts a command line argument for cross-compilation) and either builds one version or the other.